# What is a clean/concise way to pass empty range to a function taking a pair of iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I have a function that takes a pair of iterators. I'd like to provide a no-argument version of the function that behaves as if it had been passed an empty range.

To be concrete, let's say the first function is:

```
void f(vector<int>::iterator b, vector<int>::iterator e) { // impl. }
```

I'd like to write this:

```
void f() { f({}, {}); }
```

Do I have the initialisation correct here, the {}, {} should be two default constructed vector::iterator types? (It compiles).

Do I have to construct a container to get a pair of iterators that compare equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my understanding this cannot be done generally in a standard conforming way.

*24.2.1/5*:

> Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with
>   any sequence. [ Example: After the declaration of an uninitialized
>   pointer x (as with int* x;), x must always be assumed to have a
>   singular value of a pointer. — end example ] **Results of most
>   expressions are undefined for singular values**; the only exceptions are
>   destroying an iterator that holds a singular value, the assignment of
>   a non-singular value to an iterator that holds a singular value, and,
>   for iterators that satisfy the `DefaultConstructible` requirements,
>   using a value-initialized iterator as the source of a copy or move
>   operation. [ Note: This guarantee is not offered for default
>   initialization, although the distinction only matters for types with
>   trivial default constructors such as pointers or aggregates holding
>   pointers. — end note ] In these cases the singular value is
>   overwritten the same way as any other value. Dereferenceable values
>   are always non-singular.

Default/value initialisation clearly isn't associated with any sequence, so the Iterator is singular.
Comparing two singular Iterators is undefined behaviour.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i;
std::vector<int>::iterator j = i; // UB, assignment of a non-a singular value
                                  // If you pass `i` to a function, a copy is done
                                  // which also results in UB (as in Andy's answer).
```

Next try, use value-initialisation

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i{};
std::vector<int>::iterator j = i; // ok, i is value-initialized
i == j; // undefined, comparison is not explicitly non-undefined behavour
i == i; // undefined, comparison is not explicitly non-undefined behavour
```

Since we don't have more information about `vector<int>::iterator`, your approach is wrong.

What you can do is changing your `f` to a template and use a pointer:

```
template <typename Iter>
void f(Iter b, Iter e);

int *p; f(p, p); // ok, defined for pointers
```

Comment: +1  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3585.pdf for a proposal to address this.  Search for "Null Iterators".

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* the default constructor for an iterator is always equivalent to an `end`. That said, if you pass the same iterator into the function, then that's also by definition an empty range.

Since all pointers are valid iterators, you should be able to use `static_cast<int*>(NULL)` as both arguments. (Or `vector<int>::iterator()`).

Comment: This is not true. It depends on the type of iterator, in most cases a default constructed iterator is *singular* and different from `end()`. Regarding the pointers, in some implementations `std::vector<int>::iterator` is `int*`, but you cannot depend on that either, as in your particular library (and depending on compile flags) it might be something different.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the clarification! I guess when originally reading it, I had been thinking of STL-style functions that take templatized iterators as inputs. Would it true to say that `static_cast<int*>(NULL)` is a valid iterator (even if not the same type as `vector<int>::iterator`)?

Comment: Yes, iterators model the behavior of pointers, and a pointer fulfills all of the random access iterator requirements. Which is good, since it enables the use of the standard algorithms on raw memory (be it an array or a block of memory allocated with `new[]`/`malloc`)